# How to shift the gaussian curve along y-axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am generating a gaussian curve as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import math

mu = 840
def bell_curve(area, peak, base):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1440, 1440)
    sigma = area/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi)*peak)
    plt.plot(x, area*(stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)))
    plt.show()

peak = int(input('Enter the peak value:'))
area = int(input('Enter the area value:'))
base = int(input('Enter the base value:'))


bell_curve(area, peak, base)
```

where `peak` is the maximum value reached by the curve at a `mu` of 840. `Peak`, `area`, `base` will be the user input value.

Now, when the values are inputted, a general gaussian curve is plotted that starts from 0 on the y-axis. I want to shift this curve by the `base` value.

**For example:**

If the user has given the peak value as 10, then the curve, in general, starts at 0, reaches a value of 10 at the value of `mu` and again comes down to 0. But, when the user gives the `base` value as, say, 3 then the curve must start at 3, reach to a peak of 10 at the `mu` and again end at 3.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: So `area` corresponds to the area under the curve?  So that means changing the base will change your peak value and the area correct?

Comment: Please note that your equation must have fairly large area values in order to work. For instance you will not get the desired results when `area=2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the curve for a `peak` of `given_peak - base`, then shift the graph up by `base`:

```
def bell_curve(area, peak, base):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1440, 1440)
    sigma = area/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi) * (peak - base))
    plt.plot(x, area*(stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)) + base)
    plt.show()
```

With 10, 900, 5, this gives:

```
Enter the peak value:10
Enter the area value:900
Enter the base value:5
```

[image]

This will be a shorter, fatter version compared to the original which looked like:

[image]